# How to change multiple font styles in one sentence

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

```
<div class="col-md text-left mt-5">
      <h5 class="Review" style=" font-size: 24px; color: #c0bebe;">Reviews</h5>
      <ul class="list-unstyled quick-links">
        <li> <p style="color: #c0bebe; "> Google-20 reviews </p></li>
        <li><p style="color: #c0bebe;">4,9<i class="far fa-star ml-3"style="color: yellow;"></i> <i class="far fa-star"style="color: yellow;"></i> <i class="far fa-star"style="color: yellow;"></i> <i class="far fa-star"style="color: yellow;"></i> <i class="far fa-star"style="color: yellow;"></i></p></li>
        <li><p style="color: #c0bebe;">Facebook - 32 reviews</p></li>
        <li><p style="color: #c0bebe;">5,0 <i class="far fa-star ml-3"style="color: yellow;"></i> <i class="far fa-star"style="color: yellow;"></i> <i class="far fa-star"style="color: yellow;"></i> <i class="far fa-star"style="color: yellow;"></i> <i class="far fa-star"style="color: yellow;"></i></p></li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

i wanted too change the font style of Google in lato-bold and 20 reviews in to lato italic while they are next too each other.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap what you want to change in a `<span>` tag then assign the class accordingly.

You'll notice that I cleaned up the code considerably. It is much easier to read by doing it this way.

```css
p {
  color: #c0bebe;
}

.googlefont {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.reviewfont {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-style: italic;
}

i {
  color: yellow;
}

.Review {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #c0bebe;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="col-md text-left mt-5">
  <h5 class="Review">Reviews</h5>
  <ul class="list-unstyled quick-links">
    <li>
      <p> <span class="googlefont">Google</span>-<span class="reviewfont">20 reviews </span></p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>4,9<i class="fa fa-star ml-3"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i></p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Facebook - 32 reviews</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>5,0 <i class="fa fa-star ml-3"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i></p>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @WeLit Glad to help!